# How to send message from Website To Telegram direct 1 number target?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, telegram

i add the form message (html standart) and button(submit) from website to telegram APP, direct number precise: +00 123 456 789 (this is example number TARGET A).
this is for mobile (iOS,android) who has installed telegram app.

If users (any people) have not it the number contact "TARGET A" then add new contact..

If users (any people) have it the number contact "TARGET A" then send it direct in telegram app mobile..

If users (any people) have not the telegram app then re-direct other page: www.company.com/miss-telegram.html
i will write the message : sorry, you have not the app Telegram, if want to add the app telegram then click, go to link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.messenger for andorid or https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/telegram-messenger/id686449807 for Ios..

can you help me how build it?

note: i'm base html build and not expert.. i'm newbie..
note: i dont know what is best code language: javascript, html5,php,..
you can try different code for javascript, for html5, for php..to see what is best solution (easy)..

thank you
so i dont know how builds it from html standart for send to telegram direct target number..

Comment: hi, nothing to resolve this problem? instead there is similar to whatapps:   https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567